# Search is case insensitive in development but sensitive in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production-environment, case-insensitive, dev-to-production

I have a search bar that performs a case insensitive search when running on localhost in the development environment, but when I push to Heroku and run in the production environment, the search is case sensitive. Not sure what would cause this behavior.

From app\views\layouts\application.html.erb:

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-right">
    <input type="text" class="search-query span3" placeholder="Find Some Beers" name="search">
</form>
```

From app\controllers\ratings_controller.rb:

```
def search
    fff = Rating.search(params[:search])
    @ratings_by_name = fff.paginate(:order => 'name ASC', :page => params[:page], :per_page =>10)
    @ratings_by_score = fff.paginate(:order => 'score DESC', :page => params[:page], :per_page =>10)
end
```

From app\models\rating.rb:

```
def self.search(query)
    words = query.to_s.strip.split
    words.inject(scoped) do |combined_scope, word|
    combined_scope.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{word}%")
    end
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using different database in development and prod (e.g. sqlite in development and postgres in production)?

Comment: What kind of db You are using ? If mysql please provide  `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;` for a table ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku uses postgres, make sure you are using postgres in development as well.

use the ILIKE postgres case insensitive version of LIKE

```
combined_scope.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{word}%")
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Switched to postgres in development, implemented ILIKE and it works great now.